# PL/SQL NUMBERS ONLY

Tags: javascript, input, plsql

I am trying to create a numbers only text box in a PL/SQL screen. I am not very familiar with PL SQL or if this would even work.

I cant get this to work. Any suggestions?

```
htp.p('<html><head>');

htp.p('<script type="text/avascript">
  $(function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  else
    return true;
});
</script>');
htp.p('</head>');

    htp.p('<INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar">');
```

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, `text/avascript` is not a valid type.

Comment: It does not do anything. I get the text box but it does not filter out the letters

Comment: Does it give an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the function inside `$()`, thus that function is not available to the global scope. To declare it globally, use this:

```
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
</script>');
```

Should work as expected now.

[Original demo (with problem)](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/X24f4/1/).

[Fixed demo (working)](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/X24f4/).